# Doctrine: how to add a if statement in an order by condition?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to write this kind of query :

```
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('gh')
        ->orderBy("IF(gh.language = 'en', 1, 0)", 'desc')
        ->getQuery();
```

How can it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer:

Doctrine only supports a limited subset of SQL functions because it was built to be flexible and not SQL engine specific. Therefore, things like IF statements are not implemented into doctrine, and won't be implemented because the way MySQL handles IF, for example, is different from what PostgreSQL does it (it does not even exist).

However, Doctrine 2 is so powerful that allows you to write your own functions, and extend its functionality, however I wouldn't recommend this unless it's really really necessary to do so.

You can find more details about user defined functions and Doctrine in their documentation:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

What I would do, is to write raw SQL to query your database. You will have to create a custom repository to keep your code clean and organized.

The custom repositories are an "extension" of your entities.

For example, if you have an entity `GH`, then your entity class looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\ProjectName\WhateverBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * GH
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="GH")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourNamespace\ProjectName\WhateverBundle\GHRepository")
 */
class Category {}
```

Note the `repositoryClass` statement added to your annotations, that indicates where your customer repository is.

Then create a repository class in the same folder where your entity class is. The convention is to name it "Repository", so in your case it would be: `GHRepository` and extend the parent class `EntityRepository`, your custom repository class would look like this:

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\ProjectName\WhateverBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use PDO;

class GH Repository extends EntityRepository {
}
```

Then you can just create public functions inside your class that use raw SQL to query your database. The convention is to name your functions starting with `findBy` or `findAllBy` but it's not necessary.

For example, one of my functions look like this:

```
public function findAllProductsByCategory($categoryId) {
    $pdo = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $findProductsQuery =
    "SELECT
      P.*
    FROM
        Products P
        LEFT JOIN Types_Products TP ON TP.product_id = P.id
        LEFT JOIN Types T ON TP.type_id = T.id
        LEFT JOIN Categories_Types CT ON CT.type_id = T.id
        LEFT JOIN Categories C ON CT.category_id = C.id
    WHERE
        C.id = :categoryId
    GROUP BY
        P.id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($findProductsQuery);
    $stmt->bindParam(':categoryId', $categoryId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

and I can use this function, in any controller this way:

```
    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $categoryRepository = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Category');
    $products = $categoryRepository->findAllProductsByCategory($category->getId());
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however my question is specific about if statement in the orderby condition: IF(gh.language = 'en', 1, 0)"

Comment: @pico34 I understood your question, I'm telling you that the way you're trying to do it, it's plain and simple not possible. Doctrine won't allow it. You have to either create a function in doctrine, or write raw SQL for it.

Answer (score 1):

Asfar as I know you cannot do this in doctrine. In MySQL you would use `CASE` and is a vendor specific keyword.